# RequiredIf GetProperty Null Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a form field that is displayable only to guests and is required if it is displayable to guest. The issue I am having is from Extension.cs `type.GetProperty(PropertyName)` returns null in which makes the whole line return a null reference exception. I've spent some time researching what may cause this such as making sure the property is public, actually a property, etc but I am stumped.

Page.html.cs

```
 public bool IsGuest { get; set; } 

 [BindProperty]
 [RequiredIfTrue(nameof(IsGuest), ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
 [EmailAddress]
  public string GuestEmail { get; set; }

     public IActionResult OnGet()
     {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claim = "";
            if (claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
            {
                claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                IsGuest = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsGuest = true;
                claim = Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Session"];
            }
      }
```

Extention.cs

```
 public class RequiredIfTrueAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfTrueAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();

        bool.TryParse(type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance)?.ToString(), out bool propertyValue);

        if (propertyValue && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I am having is from Extension.cs
>   type.GetProperty(PropertyName) returns null in which makes the whole
>   line return a null reference exception.

This is because `context.ObjectInstance.GetType()` returns **object** type, you can't get the `IsGuest` property from **object** in reverse, so it returns null.

To be able to use RequiredIfTrueAttribute normally, you can **put the IsGuest and GuestEmail fields into a class,** and then refer to the class as the property in the page.

Here is a simple example based on your code:

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public bool IsGuest { get; set; }
        [RequiredIfTrue(nameof(IsGuest), ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string GuestEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Page:

```
   public class AttrTestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public MyModel data { get; set; } = new MyModel();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claim = "";
            if (claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
            {
                claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                data.IsGuest = false;
            }
            else
            {
                data.IsGuest = true;
                claim = Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Session"];
            }
        }
        public void OnPost()
        {

        }
    }
```

View：

```
@page
@model WebApplication_razorpage_new.Pages.AttrTestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AttrTest";
}

<h1>AttrTest</h1>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.data.IsGuest" class="control-label"></label>
        <input id="Radio1" type="radio" asp-for="@Model.data.IsGuest" value="@Model.data.IsGuest" />
    </div>
    @if (Model.data.IsGuest)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.data.GuestEmail" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.data.GuestEmail" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.data.GuestEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    }
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]